# What's is the relative sacred body part name for Lord Brahma similar to Padmanabha and Shivalinga for Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva respectively?

Tags: brahma, shiva-lingam

I have noticed that the names denoting the sacred body part of Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva are Padmanabha and Shivalinga respectively.

I am thinking "Head" is the sacred body part of Lord Brahma.

But what is the appropriate word for it similar to "Padmanabha" and "Shivalinga" described anywhere in Hindu Literature?

Comment: There's is nothing called as, "a specific sacred part of any divinity". Any material manifestations of divinity is completely sacred in any way whatsoever including all parts. Even the dust that touches their feet will be elixir. The *Shivalinga* is the primordial symbol of *Shiva+Shakti*. The *Padmanabham* is a special vyuha of Lord Narayana (Vishnu), reclining on the Ananta Shesha with a lotus sprouting from his navel on which Lord Brahmaa is depicted to be seated. It's not a symbol, but *roopam*. Shaligram is the symbol of Hari. Same goes for Lord Brahmaa, everything is sacred in his body.

Answer (score 2):

metonymy: the substitution of the name of an attribute or adjunct for that of the thing meant, for example suit for business executive, or the track for horse racing.

Padmanabha "navel-lotus-ed" is a name of Vishnu

neela-kantha "blue-mecked" is a name of Siva.

Chaturmukha "four-headed" is a name of Brahma.

This figure of speech is ubiquitous in Sanskrit - like "kiriti" = "crowned" for Arjuna.

The part used to represent the whole is not any more sacred than the rest of the body of the deity.

Comment: 